# AVPlayer Custom Button Full screen in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, fullscreen, avplayer

Still working on an app which includes video, I encounter several problems when customizing the player (you can see my question about mpmoviemediaplayer).

Here I used AVPlayerViewController in an embedded view.
I want to create several customs buttons and one is for full screen. 
If the device is in portrait so when clicking the video must appear in a landscape right mode (and same is the device rotate on the right).

I found a method but it's not very clean as I always have the status bar on top of the device when in portrait mode with the fullscreen video in landscape.

Moreover I want to overlay the button on the embedded video and one in the fullscreen video

Can anyone help me please ?

Thank you

```
let playerController:AVPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

var player:AVPlayer!
var filePath: NSURL!


@IBOutlet weak var fullscreenbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var exitfullscreenbutton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("jojo", withExtension: "mov")


    self.player = AVPlayer(URL:filePath)
    playerController.player = player

    playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)
    playerController.showsPlaybackControls = false // masque les contrôles de la vidéo
    playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerController.view.hidden = false
    self.addChildViewController(playerController)
    self.view.addSubview(playerController.view)
    playerController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    player.play()


    var currentDevice = UIDevice.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange:" , name:
    UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}


func deviceOrientationDidChange(notify: NSNotification){

    var orientation:UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation
    switch (orientation) {
    case .LandscapeLeft:
        //self.view.autoresizingMask = (.FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight | .FlexibleLeftMargin | .FlexibleRightMargin | .FlexibleTopMargin | .FlexibleBottomMargin)


       self.playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)
        break
    case .LandscapeRight:
       self.playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height)

        break
    case .PortraitUpsideDown:

        break
    case .Portrait:
        self.playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 250)
        break
    default:
        println("Unknown orientation: \(orientation)")
    }

}


@IBAction func fullScreenBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.view.autoresizingMask = (.FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleTopMargin)

    self.playerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height,  self.view.bounds.width, -self.view.bounds.height)
    self.playerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2))


}
```

Comment: Hav you sort out this issues

Comment: no sorry. I can't find any solution